# NEWID() In Joined Virtual Table Causes Unintended Cross Apply Behavior

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-internals

My actual work query was an inner join, but this simple example with cross join seems to nearly always reproduce the problem.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) AA ( A )
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT NEWID() TEST_ID
) BB ( B )
```

With my inner join I had many rows for which I added to each a GUID using the NEWID() function, and for about 9 out of 10 such rows the multiplication with the 2-row virtual table produced the expected results, just 2 copies of the same GUID, while 1 out of 10 would produce different results. This was unexpected to say the least and gave me a really hard time trying to find this bug in my test data generation script.

If you take a look at the following queries using as well non-deterministic getdate and sysdatetime functions, you won't see this, I don't anyway-I always see the same datetime value in both final result rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) AA ( A )
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT GETDATE() TEST_ID
) BB ( B )

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) AA ( A )
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT SYSDATETIME() TEST_ID
) BB ( B )
```

I'm currently using SQL Server 2008 and my work around for now is to load my rows with GUIDs into a table variable before finishing out my random data generation script. Once I have them as values in a table as opposed to virtual table, the problem goes away.

I have a workaround, but I'm looking for the ways to workaround without actual tables or table variables.

While writing this I tried without success these possibilities:
1) placing the newid() into a nested virtual table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) AA ( A )
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT TEST_ID
    FROM (
        SELECT NEWID() TEST_ID
    ) TT
) BB ( B )
```

2) wrapping the newid() within a cast expression such as:

```
SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(100)) TEST_ID
```

3) reversing the order of appearance of the virtual tables within the join expression

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NEWID() TEST_ID
) BB ( B )
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) AA ( A )
```

4) using uncorrelated cross apply

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NEWID() TEST_ID
) BB ( B )
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) AA ( A )
```

Just before finally posting this question, now I tried this with success it seems, a correlated cross apply:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NEWID() TEST_ID
) BB ( B )
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT A
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
    ) TT ( A )
    WHERE BB.B IS NOT NULL
) AA ( A )
```

Anyone have any other more elegant, simpler workaround? I really don't want to use cross apply or correlation for a simple row multiplication if I don't have to.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This behaviour is by design, as explained in detail on [this Connect bug report](https://web.archive.org/web/20150506160803/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions).  The most pertinent Microsoft reply is reproduced below for convenience (and in case the link dies at some point):

> *Posted by Microsoft on 7/7/2008 at 9:27 AM*
>
> Closing the loop . . . I've discussed this question with the Dev team.
> And eventually we have decided not to change current behavior, for the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. The optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of
>    scalar functions. This is a long-estabilished tenet. It's the
>    fundamental 'leeway' tha allows the optimizer enough freedom to gain
>    significant improvements in query-plan execution.
> 2. This "once-per-row behavior" is not a new issue, although it's not
>    widely discussed. We started to tweak its behavior back in the Yukon
>    release. But it's quite hard to pin down precisely, in all cases,
>    exactly what it means! For example, does it a apply to interim rows
>    calculated 'on the way' to the final result? - in which case it
>    clearly depends on the plan chosen. Or does it apply only to the rows
>    that will eventually appear in the completed result? - there's a nasty
>    recursion going on here, as I'm sure you'll agree!
> 3. As I mentioned earlier, we default to "optimize performance" -
>    which is good for 99% of cases. The 1% of cases where it might change
>    results are fairly easy to spot - side-effecting 'functions' such as
>    NEWID - and easy to 'fix' (trading perf, as a consequence). This
>    default to "optimize performance" again, is long-established, and
>    accepted. (Yes, it's not the stance chosen by compilers for
>    conventional programming languages, but so be it).
>
> So, our recommendations are:
>
> 1. Avoid reliance on non-guaranteed timing and number-of-executions
>    semantics.
> 2. Avoid using NEWID() deep in table expressions.
> 3. Use
>    OPTION to force a particular behavior (trading perf)
>
> Hope this explanation helps clarify our reasons for closing this bug
> as "won't fix".

The `GETDATE` and `SYSDATETIME` functions are indeed non-deterministic, but they are treated as [runtime constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions) for a particular query.  Broadly, this means [the function's value is cached](http://web.archive.org/web/20170120150651/https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/rand-and-other-runtime-constant-functions-redux/) when query execution starts, and the result re-used for all references within the query.

None of the 'workarounds' in the question are safe; there is no guarantee the behaviour will not change the next time the plan is compiled, when you next apply a service pack or cumulative update...or for other reasons.

The only safe solution is to use a temporary object of some kind - a variable, table, or multi-statement function for example. Using a workaround that appears to work today based on observation is a great way to experience unexpected behaviours in future, typically in the form of a paging alert at 3am on Sunday morning.