# Where Clause Index Scan - Index Seek

Tags: sql-server, index, execution-plan

I have below table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    col1 varchar(37) NULL,
    testDate datetime NULL 
)

GO

insert Test    
select null
go 700000 

insert Test
select cast(NEWID() as varchar(37))
go 300000
```

And below indexes:

```
create clustered index CIX on Test(ID)
create nonclustered index IX_RegularIndex on Test(col1)
create nonclustered index IX_RegularDateIndex on Test(testDate)
```

When I query on my table:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
select * from Test  where col1=NEWID()
select * from Test  where TestDate=GETDATE()
```

First is making index scan whereas the second index seek. I expect that both of them must make index seek. Why does the first make index scan?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is an implicit conversion to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type. There is a warning about it in the execution plan, and it is connected with [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

Your table is using the wrong data type to store GUIDs. If `col1` were correctly typed as [`uniqueidentifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx), your problem would never have arisen. The *string representation* of a GUID has a maximum length of 36 (not 37!) characters, which is much less efficient than using `uniqueidentifier` (16 bytes). Note also that [`NEWID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) returns a `uniqueidentifier`, not any sort of string.

I added some hints to my queries below to get an identical execution plan.

[image: Execution plan with warning]

You can avoid this if you assign `NEWID()` to a variable but you still have to declare `VARCHAR(37)` variable or just cast `NEWID()` to `VARCHAR(37)` in the where clause.

Here are a few queries that show us how it works:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT * FROM Test WITH(INDEX=[IX_RegularIndex]) WHERE col1=NEWID()
GO

-- Query 2
DECLARE @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()

SELECT * FROM Test WITH(INDEX=[IX_RegularIndex]) WHERE col1=@id
GO

-- Query 3
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(37) = NEWID()

SELECT * FROM Test WITH(INDEX=[IX_RegularIndex]) WHERE col1=@id
GO

-- Query 4
SELECT * FROM Test WITH(INDEX=[IX_RegularIndex]) WHERE col1=cast(NEWID() as varchar(37))
GO
```

[image: Query 1 -]
[image: Query 2]
[image: Query 3]
[image: Query 4]

Related Q & A concerning the number of times the `NEWID` function is evaluated:

[NEWID() In Joined Virtual Table Causes Unintended Cross Apply Behavior](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30345)